Rendering triangles using perfect circles
Note: You need to explain this in terms that a person who doesn't research geometry will understand. This is for a coding project.
This may be some help: Packing a triangle full of circles. But I still need it explained in simpler terms and with the $6$ points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ (This is the part that is different)
I'm using a simple program to make a $3d$ game, but sadly it can only render circles. Right now I'm trying to find a way to render triangles using the least possible circles and an algorithm to do it. (In a way of the most area on the screen using the least circles)
Finding where to render one circle in a equilateral triangle is proving a challenge for me, and I still have to figure out how to render multiple circles inside one that is defined by $3$ points. I'm not very good at geometry, so I have no idea where to start.
Since this may be confusing, here is a summary of what I want: Since the program I am using can only render circles, I want to replace the triangles with multiple circles that look like a triangle in the most optimal way.
An even simpler summary: What's the most optimal way to create a triangle using circles?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
